# How to delete files in Visual Studio Pre-build event command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, build-process, pre-build-event

I am trying to delete files in my `$(TargetDir)` within visual studio before building a project.

How do you have to format command line to get around this problem I am getting below?
[image]

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try

```
cd $(TargetDir)
del *.tif
```

As jvenema pointed out, your $(TargetDir) is expanding into a path containing spaces in the folder names which is breaking the delete command.

Comment: I observed that even if no spaces are in the dirname, separating into a 'cd' and a wildcard makes the difference between working and busted :/

Comment: @Eoin Could you please tell me where can I find the document of these command ? Or could you please give me the search key in the google ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Just to clarify, TargetDir is probably your bin directory.

Answer (score 33):

I ended up using `rd /s /q "$(TargetDir)"` to clean out the directory. As far as I know it is working.

Comment: This removes even there are subdirectories also by /q option it removes quietly. It means "remove directory command"(rd) never ask for deletion(R U Sure?). After any build if there is an existing file this way become better,thanks

Comment: This quietly removes the build target directory, $(TargetDir), and its contents. Visual Studio recreates the build directory when necessary.

Comment: I also found this approach useful, as 'del' will fail with the same error when the directory you're looking to delete files from doesn't exist, which is a problem when you're looking to remove all files from a directory deeper in the build output structure.

Answer (score 17):

Try adding quotes around the directory.

Comment: Thanks jvenema: It seems like "quote" actually does what I thought it should do, but unfortunately I was not delete all images using a wide-card.  Eoin's version worked though.

Answer (score 14):

You have to write `del "$(TargetDir)*.tif"` because of spaces in directory path.

Answer (score 10):

Old question but a couple of things:

```
del "$(TargetDir)*.tif" /q
```

1) /q is for quiet. Otherwise, del cmd prompts "...  Are you sure (Y/N)?" which the build does not like.

2) As many have pointed out, "" around the targetDir for possible space in the target directory.

Answer (score 0):

For `DOTNET Core`, your quotes need to be escaped, like this:

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="del &quot;$(ProjectDir)wwwroot\_framework\*.*&quot; /q" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="copy &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\Client\bin\Debug\net5.0\wwwroot\_framework\*.*&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)wwwroot\_framework\&quot;" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score -2):

wmic process where `name='chromedriver.exe' delete`