# Visual Studio 2015 - Webforms - Specific classes do not recompile?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My Visual Studio 2015 C# project has Web forms and classes defined under the `App_Code` folder. When building / rebuilding my solution, some **specific** classes under this folder never recompile - after compilation, their code is not changed (though seemingly they passed the compilation).

This shows up as run-time error messages for code I have just changed, not able to place breakpoints, etc.

I've attempted:

- Rebuild
- Clearing the ASP.NET temp folders
- (There's no "Clean solution" because this is web forms)
- Running as admin

**The only solution that works**: Reopening Visual Studio.

---

Illustration:

[image]

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I have now also found that deleting the folder `C:\Users\kobydo\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files` and then running a build also fixes this issue. But this is no real solution.

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Strange. Quick & Dirty Fix: Clear that folder in a [PreBuild Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768282/how-to-delete-files-in-visual-studio-pre-build-event-command-line)