# Force rcc-ing of qrc file on each build

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2015, qt-resource

How to force rcc-ing of a qrc file on each build in Visual Studio 2015? We are embedding the resources in the binary, so if something like qml or image assets change, we need to run rcc to get a fresh `.cpp` file for the current state. I see several options - brutally touching the `.qrc` file in a pre build event, running a script which checks everything in the asset folder before build and checking the timestamps and comparing them to a state at the previous build. Are there cleaner and more elegant options?

Comment: Doesn't VS implement a typical dependency system where if the sources change, the target is re-processed?

Comment: AFAIK, you can just run qmake in Qt Creator before building. That should ensure that the resources are kept up-to-date.

Comment: @KubaOber, yeah, but VS does not know that the resources inside the qrc file are actually dependencies of the qrc file itself. I'll check if I can add that since that makes most sense.

Comment: That's really the only sane way to go forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it was requested in the comments, I'm publishing the solution I came up with. So, in my case the `qrc` file is added to the Visual Studio solution, and has a proper Custom Build Tool set (but that is the common way and should be set up by the VS Qt plugin) like this:

[image]

All I had to do was to make a trivial C# program which reads the contents of the `qrc` and updates the modification timestamp of the `qrc` file, if any of the contained items was newer than the `qrc` itself. This is all it takes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace QrcValidator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 1)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("usage: QrcValidator.exe <qrc file path>");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Validating {0}", args[0]));
            XDocument qrcDocument = XDocument.Load(args[0]);
            var qrcFileLastWrtieTimeUtc = File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(args[0]);
            foreach (var file in qrcDocument.Descendants("RCC").Descendants("qresource").Descendants("file"))
            {
                if (File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file.Value) >= qrcFileLastWrtieTimeUtc)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} is dirty, setting last write time of {1} to current UTC time", file.Value, args[0]);
                    File.SetLastWriteTimeUtc(args[0], DateTime.UtcNow);
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This tool takes the `qrc` file as the first argument. So I just added calling this tool as a pre build event, and if any changes have happened to the resources, the `qrc` file is touched, and it's normal build command is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use CMake, you could add a pre-build task to delete the `your-project-name_autogen` folder from the build directory. This forces CMake to rcc the qrc file each build.

The command might look something like:

```
add_custom_command (TARGET your-project-name PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/your-project-name_autogen)
```

CMake does this by adding a Pre-Build Event to its generated Visual Studio project, so you can also replicate it with only Visual Studio. If you haven't found the pre-build event section already, right-click on the desired project (not solution), and select `Properties`. Under `Build Events`, there should be a section called `Pre-Build Events`. A command like `del your-files` would probably suffice.

The answer linked below gave some other decent options.

[How to delete files in Visual Studio Pre-build event command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768282/how-to-delete-files-in-visual-studio-pre-build-event-command-line)

The CMake command was the solution to my issues with a Qt qrc file containing QML resources.

Comment: I actually fixed this with making a custom tool that compares the resource modification stamps against the last build and invokes the Qt resource tool only if something has changed. The the VS build events (which is what CMake would generate in this case) can't achieve this on their own since they do not perform any such checks.

Comment: Is this something that might be reusable for others with the same problem? If you're willing to share the source, I'd be down to test adapting it to my current project. @RudolfsBundulis

Comment: I added the code of the tool I used for updating the qrc timestamp in a an answer. I thought it was so trivial that I didn't post it here.